# Can I write JSON data to a file in iOS/Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c, ios

I need to write JSON data to a file using Objective-C. My data looks something like this:

```
data = {
    "NrObjects" : "7",
    "NrScenes" : "5",
    "Scenes" : [
        { "dataType" : "label", "position" : [20, 20, 300, 300], "value" : "Hello" },
        { "dataType" : "label", "position" : [20, 60, 300, 300], "value" : "Hi There" }
    ]
}
```

It may get more complex than this, but what I need to know is whether I can do this with Obj-C, i.e., create an object of this form, write the data to a file, and read it back.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There is a class specifically made for this, its called **NSJSONSerialization**.

You read it like this:

```
NSArray* jsonResponse = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:theResponse
                                                        options:kNilOptions
                                                          error:&error];
```

and write it like this:

```
NSData* jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:userDetails
                                                   options:kNilOptions 
                                                     error:&error];
```

Comment: Just to add : this API is available in iOS 5 and later

Comment: Thanks a lot. I didn't know that existed in Obj-C. That's exactly what I needed.

Comment: @IIS7Rewrite if this answer is useful for you, please do not forget to mark it as accepted, thanks.

Comment: @LuisOscar if you thought the question was useful and clear, you should up vote it.

Answer (score 6):

write:

```
NSData *data = [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject:jsonObject];
[data writeToFile:path atomically:YES];
```

read:

```
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:path];
NSDictionary *jsonObject = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:data];
```